# How to loop through a webtable using HP UFT and print the text for each row in column 1 and 2

Tags: hp-uft

Hello can someone help me loop through a web table using HP UFT to read a WebTable and loop through each row, print the text for each row in column 1 and 2 and finally compare the text to whats on the webpage

```
Set myTable = Browser("page").Page("activity Center").WebTable("readonlygrid-xxxx")


TotalRows =  myTable.RowCount 
msgbox TotalRows
Total = 0


For i = 2 to TotalRows 
   For x = 2 to TotalRows

strinbx = myTable.GetCellData(i,1)
strinbx2 = myTable.GetCellData(x,2)

print strinbx & strinbx2

Next
Next
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem you're having?  You haven't actually said.

Comment: I would like to use a spreadsheet I get from the data group and compare whats on the screen to each row of data in the spreadsheet. So for example when I read in row 1 on the page, I should get 2 separate values( 'datacode, description') I need to compare both values that i have captured to be sure it matches with the spreadsheet values that the data team has given to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have two loops for the rows. If you only want the first two columns of each row you need something like this:

```
For row = 1 to myTable.RowCount
    column1 = myTable.GetCellData(row, 1)
    column2 = myTable.GetCellData(row, 1)
    Print column1 & " - " & column2
Next
```

I also don't understand what you mean by "compare the text to whats on the webpage", the values you get are what's on the webpage.